# Php not working in form

Tags: php, session, post

**Update**
My Page is not pulling information from the form for some reason it wants to keep all the fields empty even though if it is checked it should change the value of the QuestionOptionId. What i want it to do is when you check the radio button it saves the value to the session so it can be submitted later like a quiz. For some reason my code wont change the value or even obtain the value of QuestionOptionId

Code below

```
<?php
session_start();
//check if the user is already logged in.
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
$QuestionOptionId = "";
//get value from post data and store into session
if (isset($_POST['QuestionOptionId'])){
    $_SESSION['QuestionOptionId'] = $_POST['QuestionOptionId'];
}
//get back from session
if (isset($_SESSION['QuestionOptionId'])){
    $QuestionOptionId = $_SESSION['QuestionOptionId'];
}
print $_SESSION['username'];
?>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","root") or die();
                //execute query
                $query ="SELECT UserId from user where username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";     
                $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
                $UserId=$result->num_rows;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  

   echo $row['UserId']; 
   $UserId=$row['UserId'];//etc...
 }

?>

<body>
    <header>
        <p class="text-center">
            Welcome :<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];
                            echo $UserId;
                    ?>
                </p>
                <?php 
                        $query="SELECT * from testview";
                        $res=mysqli_query($con, $query);
                        $rows=$res->num_rows;
                            $i=1;
                        while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                {?>
                   <?php if($i==1){?>
                   <div id='question<?php   echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                   <form name="QuestionTime"Method="post" action="push.php">
                  <p class='questions' id="qtext<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['QuestionText'];?></p>
                  <input <?php if ($QuestionOptionId=='3'){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?>type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QuestionOptionId'];?>'name="1"/>

                  <?php
                  $query="SELECT OptionChoiceName FROM testview WHERE OptionChoiceId=3";
                        $res=mysqli_query($con, $query);
                        $rows=$res;
                            $i=1;
                          while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($res))

                 echo  $result['OptionChoiceName'];?>

                  <input <?php if ($QuestionOptionId=='4'){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="radio" value="2"id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QuestionId'];?>'name="1"/>
                  <?php

                  $query="SELECT OptionChoiceName FROM testview WHERE OptionChoiceId=4";
                        $res=mysqli_query($con, $query);
                        $rows=$res;
                            $i=1;

                          while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($res))

                 echo  $result['OptionChoiceName'];

                 ?>

<br><br>Selected Value: <?php echo $QuestionOptionId; ?>

                  <br/>

                  <?php  

                    $_SESSION['UserId']=$UserId;
                  ?>

                 <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='submit'>Finish</button>
                 </div> 
                    <?php } $i++;} ?>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    </header></header>
```

any help would be grand thanks

Comment: can you extend on this answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not fethcing `QuestionOptionId` & `QuestionId`. Try with this query -

```
SELECT OptionChoiceName, QuestionOptionId, QuestionId FROM testview WHERE OptionChoiceId=3
```

This should be -

```
if(isset($_SESSION['QuesitonOptionId']))
{
    $QuestionOptionId= $_SESSION['QuesitonOptionId'];
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same errors sadly :( 
I think its something to do with the form input as when its displayed as php  im getting something like this type="radio" value="4" name="1"/> False  instead of this showing the radio button